# How do I remove Windows 7 from a dual-boot install with Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, multi-boot, reinstall

So I've been running Ubuntu alongside Windows 7 for a year or so.

Is there a way to remove Windows 7 from my system without having to reinstall Ubuntu from scratch so I can use all the disk space?

Or would it be faster just to reinstall Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Off topic, but anyway:

The simplest way is to

- get rid of the windows installation (just reformat the related partition)
- run `sudo update-grub`

Done. Alternatively, you could hand edit the grub config (/etc/grub.d/*) but I don't recommend it.

**Edit** You *COULD* leave everything as is, and edit the default in /etc/default/grub

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=1
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=3
```

(assuming Ubuntu is the first in the grub menu). This will prevent the boot selection menu from showing up, without *actually* changing the dual boot config

Comment: thnx for your answer. Can i format the windows partition that is on the same disk as my ubuntu install from ubuntu? and if so how?

Comment: @FLY yes; (1) be careful, don't wipe the wrong stuff (2) use [gparted GUI partitioner](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GParted) or (2b) `blkid` to spot the partition, `mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdXY` (where sdXY is the partition found earlier).

Comment: so the windows partition shows up as /dev/sdXY with partition and file system unallocated?

Comment: @FLY: you mean, after that? Yes/no: in fact it will be formatted as an empty (ext4) filesystem), that won't be _mounted_ if that is what you mean. You can do whatever you want with the space (including, say, mounting it). See http://askubuntu.com/ or http://superuser.stackexchange.com for general partitioning guidance

Comment: nope I mean after I open gparted GUI. I have 2 locations `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdb` . `/dev/sda` contains 2 partions `/media/sytem reserved` and `/host` in `/dev/sda1` `/dev/sda2`.   `/dev/sdb` contains an unallocated partition. my questions is how do i find out which one is my windows partion or does it mean i have 2 hdd in this pc?

Comment: @FLY: it will basically just 'tell you' (usually because it it `NTFS`, which is the windows filesystem, but likely also because of the volume lables). Like I said, post _that_ question on superuser (include a screenshot or the output of `sudo blkid`)

Comment: Aah i see now stackoverflow is only for program / code related questions. will update the question. thnx!

Answer (score 0):

It depends how you want to use the space that your old operating system used; if you want to make it another filesystem that you mount via `/etc/fstab`, then you can simply reformat it with `mkfs(8)`, add the appropriate `mount(8)` options to your `fstab(5)`, and go for it.

If you want it to be part of your `/home` or `/` partition transparently -- which is nice for not having to manage your storage explicitly -- then a complete re-install is the easier approach.

My suggestion is to use it as a `/movies` or `/home` or something until it is time to buy a new drive -- but that's primarily because I'm lazy.